# Convert a pdf with editable fields to html

Tags: java, javascript, html, pdf

I want to know whether it's possible to convert a pdf with editable fields to a html(having an background image and editable fields above the image) programatically and vice versa?

Are there any good libraries avaiable?

My technology stack is Java, Html and JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

i think this library will help you.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdftohtml/